# Can i store HTML files in drawable folde and use them for webview

Tags: android

How to store html files in Drawable in resource and access them.
I want html files inside the application i don't want to link them from localhost or from sdcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead copy your html file in `assets` directory and use it as follows

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YourWebView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your.html");
```

You can not add html files in drawable folders because drawable directory is used for different purpose as follows from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html).

> Though usually not visible to the application, Drawables may take a
>   variety of forms:
>
> Bitmap: the simplest Drawable, a PNG or JPEG image.
>
> Nine Patch: an extension to the PNG format allows it to specify 
>   information about how to stretch it and place things inside of it.
>
> Shape: contains simple drawing commands instead of a raw bitmap,
>   allowing it to resize better in some cases.
>
> Layers: a compound drawable, which draws multiple underlying drawables
>   on top of each other.
>
> States: a compound drawable that selects one of a set of drawables
>   based on its state.    Levels: a compound drawable that selects one of
>   a set of drawables based on its level.    Scale: a compound drawable
>   with a single child drawable, whose overall size is modified based on
>   the current level.

Comment: @Rahul Yes it will work. Thanks for credits It Motivate us to help :)

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to create `assets` folder in you `main` directory and paste html file in it and load that file with following code :

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.YOURID);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/*.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't load html files from **drawable** folders. For that you have to keep your html files in **assets** folder, and from there you can load these files in your webview.

Use the following code to do so.

```
WebView mWebView = null;
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html");
```

To create assets folder **right click on app folder** and then navigate to **Folder menu**. From that select **Assets folder** . It will create your assets folder in proper place.

Comment: is that asset folder will include in apk when i will build

Comment: yes you have to create assets folder under res directory of your project.

Comment: sorry by mistake I described the wrong place for creating assets folder. I have updated it in my answer

Comment: As of 2020, the assets folder has to be created beside /res to work, not inside res/.